# Cannot launch my PHP project on Aptana Studio 3

Tags: php, aptana

I'm trying to launch a PHP file using Apatana Studio 3 but I get the following message :

---

Unexpected error

Failed to launch on PHP Server

Reason :

Could not create a default server for the launch

---

I have installed Wamp and the server is running(green). I can access the localhost page. Also the default workspace has been switched for www.

Which settings should I change to have this php file working ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of my problem.
What I had to do was to go into the folder "wamp/www/", open index.php and search for $suppress_localhost and set its value to false. 
After restarting the server I could access my project directly from localhost in wamp.